# Distributed filesystem for automated offline data mirroring

Tags: linux, backup, distributed-filesystems

I'd like to achieve the following setup:

**Every time I connect my laptop to a local network, my partition gets automatically mirrored to a partition on my local server.**

I only want to mirror what has changed from the last time. (I understand that it is not a proper backup solution since there is no history of the changes, it'd be more like a non-persistent network RAID.)

Is there a distributed file system that allows such a setup? I've done some searching and it seems to me that most distributed file-systems are focused on data availability and distribution, not duplicating them.

I'd be thankful for suggestions.

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot to mention: I'm using Linux.

Comment: what OS do you use?

Comment: what would you lack using an rsync job ? (could be triggered as post-up interface script)

Comment: i'm with silopolis use rsync

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are vaguely describing [AFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System) in it's disconnected mode of operation.  However, I don't see any articulated requirement for the use of a "distributed" filesystem to solve your problem.

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/), [bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/) and many others (not to mention the "dropbox" like family of cloud solutions) could provide this functionality.  If the goal is for automatic sync upon network connection invoking these tools via a crontab entry that first checks for connectivity or even on a udev network interface event shouldn't be very difficult.